# Is there a key that will always come last when a dictionary is sorted?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with many keys and I would like to add a dummy key which should always come last when the dictionary is sorted.  And the sort is case insensitive.  I was thinking of the using the last word in the dictionary `'zyzzyva'`.  Would that work?  And what if my keys are directory paths, where they can have /, ., etc...

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. Are you talking about producing a sorted list of the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: I thought python dict aren't ordered?

Comment: Do you mean to use an https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict?

Comment: And `zyzzyva` is only going to be last if there is not another key that starts with `'zz'`, or with `'zyzzz`, or `'zyzzyw'`, etc.

Comment: if it comes to sorting of a string then I would suggest you using `~` as it would always be at the last while sorting a string.

Comment: @anmol_uppal: No it isn't. If this is Python 2.x, '\x7f', or the first byte of almost any non-ASCII character if his encoding is UTF-8, or almost any non-ASCII character if his encoding is Latin-1 or similar, etc. are all `> '~'`. If this is Python 3.x, then of course it goes by Unicode rules rather than just byte comparisons, but many Unicode characters are `> '~'`.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this? Maybe adding a value to the end of the list that you get after sorting is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an ad-hoc object that is always the last when sorted:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Last(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False
```

Here's an usage example:

```
>>> sorted([Last(), 'c', 'a', 'b'])
['a', 'b', 'c', <__main__.Last object at 0x7f8db518d2e8>]
```

---

If you need something that is a string, then consider using `'\xff'`. If all of your keys are alphanumeric (in the sense that they are composed by the letters A-Z and the digits 0-9), then there are no chances of items greater than `'\xff'` to appear.

```
>>> sorted(['\xff', 'c', 'a', 'b'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ÿ']
```

Beware, however, that in some encodings (including UTF-8) the `'\xff'` character is used.

If you are using Unicode strings (or are using Python 3), then `u'\uffff'` may be a good alternative to `'\xff'`.

Comment: Everything before the last part is great, but all of his keys aren't alphanumeric if some of his keys are directory paths. And, since he hasn't told us whether this is Python 2.x or 3.x, there could be roughly 1 million characters that are greater than `'\xff'`.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but also wanted to mention `__cmp__` when rich comparison methods not used, but I guess there is no need, why am I even commenting, well done! :)

Comment: If he wants a string, just use `class Last(str):` and then initialise it `Last('<the end>')`

Comment: For example: `sorted(['\xff', 'c', 'a', 'b', '\u1000'])` gives you `['a', 'b', 'c', 'ÿ', 'က']`.

Comment: Your edited version is still wrong. First, `\ufffff` is two characters, `U+FFFF` and `f`. Second, `'\U00100000'` is obviously > `'\uffff'` or `'\U000fffff'`, whichever one you meant.

Comment: Besides, none of that matters given that we already know his strings aren't alphanumeric anyway.

Comment: @Duncan: subclassing `str` may or may not be possible, depending on the case. There are several C modules that use `PyUnicode_CheckExact`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: But you will get a nice clear exception in those cases. The bigger problem is that some C modules may just assume that if you've got a `PyUnicode`, you can compare the buffers directly, which would silently do the wrong thing. I don't know of any such modules, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I think your solution addresses the larger question. The item has to come in *last*. Doesn't matter if its a string or not, so your first solution really does the whole trick wonderfully.

Comment: I really think you should get rid of the second part, because the first part is a near-perfect answer, while the second part is both wrong and irrelevant. But I upvoted for the first part anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of the using the last word in the dictionary 'zyzzyva'. Would that work?

Well, that depends on your data. Are your keys all dictionary words in English? Then it will work. But if your keys can be arbitrary word-like strings, then you could have `'zzz'`. Or if they can be non-English words, you may have one that starts with a letter that comes after `'z'`. And if they're not even words, they could have characters that come after any letter.

And since you said your keys may be directory paths, they're obviously not all English words.

---

One possibility is to create a class whose members compare larger than any string:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class StringInfinity(str):
    def __new__(cls):
        return str.__new__(StringInfinity, 'I am the biggest string')
    def __lt__(self, other): return False
    def __eq__(self, other): return isinstance(other, StringInfinity)

>>> s = StringInfinity()
>>> s
'I am the biggest string'
>>> s > 'zzz'
True
```

---

Note that there are some edge cases where `str` subclasses can be a problem, but I don't think you're likely to need to worry.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* A few C extension modules expect a `str` to be *exactly* a `str`, and not a subclass. If you pass all of your keys to such a module, you'll get a `TypeError`. This is rare, easy to detect, and easy to work around (e.g., just pass `str(key)` instead of `key`). More seriously, it's conceivable that a C extension module could just assume that any `str` is exactly a `str`, without checking for it, and, say, compare the buffers directly. Which will silently do the wrong thing. I don't know if anyone's ever written such a module, and I don't know if you care about comparisons beyond the original call to sort the dict keys, but that would be harder to detect and work around if it did come up.</sub>